# How to use two bootstrap form wizard in same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

This is my form wizard based on Bootstrap, Formvalidation, and Fuel UX Wizard.

```
<!-- start first form -->
<h2 class="page-header text-center">The First Form Wizard</h2>
<div class="fuelux">
    <div class="wizard" id="orderWizard">
        <ul class="steps">
            <li data-step="1" class="active"><span class="badge">1</span> Add to cart<span class="chevron"></span></li>
            <li data-step="2"><span class="badge">2</span> Shipping address<span class="chevron"></span></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="actions">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>Prev</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next" data-last="Order">Next<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
        </div>

        <form id="orderForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="step-content">
                <!-- The first panel -->
                <div class="step-pane active" data-step="1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Quantity</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Size</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="s" /> S</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="m" /> M</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="l" /> L</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="xl" /> XL</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Color</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="white" /> White</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="black" /> Black</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red" /> Red</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="yellow" /> Yellow</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="green" /> Green</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- The second panel -->
                <div class="step-pane" data-step="2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>

                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Phone number</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cellPhone" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Street</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">City</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Zipcode</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipCode" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="thankModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thank you</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="text-center">Thank you for your order</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- start second form -->
<h2 class="page-header text-center">The Second Form Wizard</h2>
<div class="fuelux">
    <div class="wizard" id="orderWizard">
        <ul class="steps">
            <li data-step="1" class="active"><span class="badge">1</span> Add to cart<span class="chevron"></span></li>
            <li data-step="2"><span class="badge">2</span> Shipping address<span class="chevron"></span></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="actions">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>Prev</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next" data-last="Order">Next<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
        </div>

        <form id="orderForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="step-content">
                <!-- The first panel -->
                <div class="step-pane active" data-step="1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Quantity</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Size</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="s" /> S</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="m" /> M</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="l" /> L</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="xl" /> XL</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Color</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="white" /> White</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="black" /> Black</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red" /> Red</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="yellow" /> Yellow</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="green" /> Green</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- The second panel -->
                <div class="step-pane" data-step="2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>

                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Phone number</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cellPhone" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Street</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">City</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Zipcode</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipCode" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="thankModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thank you</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="text-center">Thank you for your order</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This Java

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#orderForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        // This option will not ignore invisible fields which belong to inactive panels
        excluded: ':disabled',
        fields: {
            quantity: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The quantity is required'
                    },
                    greaterThan: {
                        value: 1,
                        message: 'The quantity must be greater than 0'
                    },
                    integer: {
                        message: 'The quantity must be a number'
                    }
                }
            },
            'size[]': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The size is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            'color[]': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The color is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            firstName: {
                row: '.col-xs-4',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The first name is required'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/,
                        message: 'The first name can only consist of alphabetical and space'
                    }
                }
            },
            lastName: {
                row: '.col-xs-4',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The last name is required'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/,
                        message: 'The last name can only consist of alphabetical and space'
                    }
                }
            },
            cellPhone: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The phone number is required'
                    },
                    phone: {
                        country: 'US',
                        message: 'The value is not valid US phone number'
                    }
                }
            },
            street: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The street is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            city: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The city is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            zipCode: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The zip code is required'
                    },
                    zipCode: {
                        country: 'US',
                        message: 'The value is not valid US zip code'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('#orderWizard')
        // Call the wizard plugin
        .wizard()

        // Triggered when clicking the Next/Prev buttons
        .on('actionclicked.fu.wizard', function(e, data) {
            var fv         = $('#orderForm').data('formValidation'), // FormValidation instance
                step       = data.step,                              // Current step
                // The current step container
                $container = $('#orderForm').find('.step-pane[data-step="' + step +'"]');

            // Validate the container
            fv.validateContainer($container);

            var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($container);
            if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
                // Do not jump to the target panel
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        })

        // Triggered when clicking the Complete button
        .on('finished.fu.wizard', function(e) {
            var fv         = $('#orderForm').data('formValidation'),
                step       = $('#orderWizard').wizard('selectedItem').step,
                $container = $('#orderForm').find('.step-pane[data-step="' + step +'"]');

            // Validate the last step container
            fv.validateContainer($container);

            var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($container);
            if (isValidStep === true) {
                // Uncomment the following line to submit the form using the defaultSubmit() method
                // fv.defaultSubmit();

                // For testing purpose
                $('#thankModal').modal();
            }
        });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#orderWizard')
        .on('changed.fu.wizard', function(e, data) {
            var $body  = $('body'),
                $iframe = $body.data('iframe.fv');
            if ($iframe) {
                // Adjust the height of iframe
                $iframe.height($body.height());
            }
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q4f0ogud/1/

This form wizard is working great but when add it twice or more in the same page, the first one work and the second doesn't.

Are there any solution for that problem?
I tried replace all `#orderForm` in java with `.form-horizontal`, Both forms work but when fill the first form and click next button, the second form prevent me becouse fields is empty.

I want every forms to work independently.

Thank you, i hope that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a different id for each one of the form wizards([ids always need to be unique on html](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)), and initialize each wizard individually i.e. `(#id).wizard()` will need to happen twice, one for each different id.